# multi monitor public information display (4 monitor / each with one chrome/firefox window)

Tags: linux, bash, google-chrome, firefox-addon, multiscreen

I've 4 monitors connected to a pc running CentOS 7. Each physical monitor/display should show a website in full screen and auto refresh it every x seconds.

I've tried:

- opening from bash and moving with xdotool -> how can I distinguish between the 4 chrome or firefox windows? If I don't do it and apply to the last active this might become unreliable with other programs open.
- researched devilspie, seems it has the same problem (can't distinguish between multiple chrome/firefox windows)
- using DISPLAY variable -> does only find one display 0.0
- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/monitor-master/ -> does not work with extended workspace, contacted developer

I've only a xrandr bash script to rearrange the displays when they become connected (three of four may be switched off to save power).

I would use a firefox/chrome add on for the auto refresh functionality.

Maybe someone can give me a hint how to reliably do this?

Comment: I type "make chrome auto" in Google and before I can type " refresh", its the first suggestion...apparently "easy auto refresh" plugin will do it.  ??

Comment: autorefresh is not the problem. I'm stuck with moving the correct window to the coordinates.

Maybe start it from a bash script, get the PID and use it for xdotool

Comment: Just reread your post..I doubt you'll find anything that handles when the monitor(s) is off. Hopefully someone else answers and proves me wrong :)

Comment: In Firefox I do this in my addon NativeShot, can you please test it to ensure that it opens a window on each monitor - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - if it works right let me know and I'll share with you how I accomplished it. How are you getting the information on all the monitors right now? When the monitor is off it should not get a window in my addon, the multi monitor detection code works like that.

Comment: yes, multi monitor detection works, currently I'm opening chrome windows from a python script, use theri pid and xdotool to move them to the desired position. I'm searching for a really easy solution.

Comment: finally, after a couple of hours I've found a solution: https://www.overclockers.at/linux_bsd_and_others/linux-und-der-dual-screen-anwendung-auf-spezifisch_235127

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "easy auto refresh" chrome plugin. I have another idea for you, why not use a chrome extension for handling the positioning.
It is of course, only for chrome(maybe thats fine for you).

Background: We had related difficulties. Internal webapp that opens multiple documents in windows, and need to be placed in other monitors.
The javascript does not support this, for security reasons and only a native extension can properly work with the tabs/windows objects.

Therefore, we have created an open source chrome extension for doing exactly that: flexible windows position across multi-monitor setups.

In your case you can define for each monitor a website-rule that the window would appear there.

The chrome extension is called "MultiWindow Positioner" and its complete free. You can get it at the chrome store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiwindow-positioner/hmgehpjpfhobbnhhelhlggjfcaollidl?hl=de)

The actual source code you find in github in the project [chrome-multiwindow-positioner](https://github.com/ControlExpert/chrome-multiwindow-positioner)

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the open source (MIT) github project. If there any interesting idea, or comments feel free to share them [here](https://github.com/ControlExpert/chrome-multiwindow-positioner/issues).

Comment: I've already found a way to do it. I'm using python3 with selenium, open a new firefox windows (this solution works best even with multiple windows), move it to a specific screen (accourding coordinates), emulate f11 to make it full screen.